# Does my databaseChangeLog hierarchy make sense?

Tags: liquibase

We are looking to replace various home-grown and manual database deployment processes with liquibase. We have dozens on databases that we'd like to eventually be using liquibase for. Many of the databases have hundreds of object already in them.

After experimenting with liquibase for a while this is what I've come up with an I want to see if anyone sees any obvious drawbacks.

Since some databases have hundreds of objects I have broken up the databaseChangeLogs by object type. I have a main databaseChangeLog file that looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
 <include file="migrations/_tables.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 <include file="migrations/_triggers.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 <include file="migrations/_views.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 <include file="migrations/_stored_procedures.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

So when a migration runs it will first do schema changes in _tables.xml, then triggers in _triggers.xml and so on.

The _triggers.xml databaseChangeLog looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
 <changeSet id="tr_names_delete" author="PROD-1235" runOnChange="true" > <sqlFile path="triggers/tr_names_delete.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" /> </changeSet>
 <changeSet id="tr_names_insert" author="PROD-1235" runOnChange="true" > <sqlFile path="triggers/tr_names_insert.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" /> </changeSet>
 <changeSet id="tr_names_update" author="PROD-1235" runOnChange="true" > <sqlFile path="triggers/tr_names_update.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" /> </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I have one change set for each object. So that I can track the changes over time in the DATABASECHANGELOG table I am using the object name as the ID of the changeset and our JIRA issue as the author. So the ID would remain the same over time but developers would update the author each time they change an object. The databaseChangeLogs for stored procedures, views, etc. that can all be updated and rerun over time follow this same form.

Does anyone see any problems with this approach?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `logicalFilePath` to your changelogs to have the same path in databasechangelog if you execute changelogs with different classpaths
- I wouldn't use `runAllways=true` for procedures. Imagine the situation when you want to return to previous version. It is better (imho) to have append only changelog and use `rollback` pointing to previous version.
- Sometimes you can have dependencies between types (view in trigger, function in procedure, ...). For that the order in which you specified execution in your main changelog won't work. But it's ok to add those changes to separate changelog (`uncategorized-changes.xml` for example).
- if you want to support multiple database types, be prepared for that you will need some configuration for some functionalities (for example `sysdate` vs `now()` vs `current_date`...). For that prepare some file in which you define those configuration as properties and then include that file in your main changelog.

In other ways your changelogs looks ok.